# TclError matplotlib 1.5.0

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using the code below, a TclError is generated.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], 'ro')
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

When I execute my script in terminal, I get the following:

```
/Users/<username>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1035: UserWarning: Duplicate key in file "/Users/<username>/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc", line #2
  (fname, cnt))
objc[44479]: Class TKApplication is implemented in both /Users/<username>/anaconda/lib/libtk8.5.dylib and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[44479]: Class TKMenu is implemented in both /Users/<username>/anaconda/lib/libtk8.5.dylib and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[44479]: Class TKContentView is implemented in both /Users/<username>/anaconda/lib/libtk8.5.dylib and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[44479]: Class TKWindow is implemented in both /Users/<username>/anaconda/lib/libtk8.5.dylib and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2016-02-01 20:45:40.991 python[44479:21064918] setCanCycle: is deprecated.  Please use setCollectionBehavior instead
2016-02-01 20:45:41.000 python[44479:21064918] setCanCycle: is deprecated.  Please use setCollectionBehavior instead
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 283, in resize
    self.show()
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 355, in draw
    tkagg.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer._renderer, colormode=2)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 30, in blit
    id(data), colormode, id(bbox_array))
TclError
```

What is causing this error? I have tried adding `backend: TkAgg` to my `matplotlibrc` file, to no avail.

Please advise

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out:

Instead of using:

```
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

use:

```
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
```

or any other backend

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'TkAgg' but need to install Tkinter not with conda. The Anaconda packages for pil/pillow and matplotlib seem not to have TK properly included. Install pip with conda and then run pip install pillow matplotlib (Linux)

On windows you can use the packages from gohlke
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
install with  --force-reinstall pillow matplotlib

then Tkinter TkAgg will work.